# Phrases about a journey in BrE and AmE

Tags: meaning

What is the common phrases in BrE and AmE to say someone when he/she is beginning a journey?

I know that in BrE we can say (according to http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/journey_1):

'Have a good journey!'
'Safe journey!'

but what should we say in AmE?

Can we ask in AmE: 'Was the journey long?' when we meet somebody at the station?

**Edit**: And what about a flight?
'Have a good flight!' is common for BrE and AmE?

Comment: We'd say, "how was your trip?" and "have a safe trip!"

Comment: @KristinaLopez How about "Godspeed on your trip!". Do you folks say that occasionally?

Comment: @NourishedGourmet Sure — a couple hundred years ago, maybe. :)

Comment: @KristinaLopez Wow!

Comment: @KristinaLopez Then check out this hundred year old "relic" https://mobile.twitter.com/Bradpettit220/status/434304075945877504?screen_name=Bradpettit220

Comment: Maybe I hang with an artsy-fartsy crowd but we *do* say "Godspeed!" to travelers. lol!

Comment: ...and that was @tchrist that disparaged the expression, not me! :-)

Comment: GR. There's even an [About.com](http://esl.about.com/od/beginnerpronunciation/a/travel.htm) page with some.

Comment: It jargogles the brain to think that, mayhaps, someone would use an archaic term such as godspeed! ;-) http://www.buzzfeed.com/lukelewis/27-delightful-obsolete-words-its-high-time-we-revived

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ironically, one of the most common ways to wish somebody a nice trip in American English is to use a French loan: *Bon voyage!*

Also common for departures:

> Have a safe trip!
>   Have a nice flight!
>   Have fun in [destination]!
>   Farewell!
>   Safe travels!
>   Happy trails!

And arrivals:

> How was your trip?
>   How was your flight?
>   I hope you had a nice flight!
>   Did you have any trouble getting here?